# Can we record only some simulation results in omnet++ instead of all simulation results?

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating a large sensor network, and I want to know if there is a way to record only some simulation results instead of all results. If yes, how to specify results I want to record. Does recording few results instead of all have an impact on the simulation time?

Comment: In OMNeT++ a _parameter_ is used to control simulation. Parameters are set in omnetpp.ini. Do you really ask about recording parameters into results files?

Comment: Yes Jerzy, I am asking about recording parameters into results files. When I simulate  with 100 repetition using 10, 50, 100, 200 nodes, I have very big .sca files. I want to record only parameters I need to generate graphs.

Comment: So actually, you ask about **results recording** not [parameters](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:parameters). I suggest changing the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy, I changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vector-recording` and `scalar-recording` in `omnetpp.ini` is the simplest way to  [control result items](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:disabling-result-items).

An example.
Let's assume that there are 10 hosts, and `lostPackets` scalar is recorded. But we want to record this scalar only for `host[2]` and `host[3]`. So we can write in `omnetpp.ini`:

```
**.host[2].somemodule1.somemodule2.lostPackets.scalar-recording = true 
**.host[3].somemodule1.somemodule2.lostPackets.scalar-recording = true 
**.host[*].somemodule1.somemodule2.lostPackets.scalar-recording = false
```

It is worth to notice, that [more advanced](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:configuring-recording-modes) control of recording results is available when Signal-Based Statistics are used.

It is difficult to say what is impact of recording results into simulation efficiency - it depends on many factors (e.g. how often vector entries are recorded, how many modules record items).

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable and disable result](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:disabling-result-items) and select [different recording modes](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:vector-recording-intervals) from the **ini file**.

If you have too many values in your .sca files, you can also simply filter them from the **Browse Data** interface (where you access all the recorded values).

[image]